# How to send different http requests at the same time in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, api-testing

I need to send many http requests (E.g: 500 http request) with different data (E.g: 500 data) at the same time. How can I do it?

Example: abc.com/path?param1=xyz&param2=qwe

'xyz' and 'qwe' are different with each http request.
Method: post

Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want to send 500 different requests from one sampler at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Given you have 500 threads in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) it shouldn't be a problem to send 500 requests at the same time, all you need is:

1. Depending on where these `xyz` and `qwe` values live you can use either [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) or [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) functions if the values are in file or [JDBC PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PreProcessor) if they're in a database instead of hard-coded values in the request.
2. Add a [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) as a child of your request and set `Number of Simulated Users to Group by` to `500` - this way JMeter will fire the requests at exactly the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to send different data in each request.

All you need to do is to have the data into a csv file with headers `param1,param2` and followed by data in each row.

In the test, use the csv data and read it and pass the values to the http request.

For more details, please refer the below documentation:
https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG